# GAE model hooks not working on admin server. Why?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, entities, app-engine-ndb

I have a _pre_delete_hook that works ok for all of my deletes upon entity keys.

The problem is that when I manually delete an entity from the interactive Datastore Viewer the _pre_delete_hook **does not run**. I suppose that this applies to also any other hook.

Is that a normal behavior? And if yes why?

Btw the code for the hook:

```
@classmethod
def _pre_delete_hook(cls, key):
  info = PersonInfo.query(ancestor=key).get()
  info.key.delete()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datastore viewer is a viewer of datastore. It knows nothing about your class methods and logic behind them. Therefore; it won't work with either ndb cache (need to clean the cache by hand) or model hook.

Comment: Thanks. I see your point. I though it was aware of my models and methods in order to list them.